# Getting the key value paired differences in two data rows?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, ado.net

Alright, so I need to get the key value paired differences of two data rows. In short, I'm sending an email to let a user know they've made specific changes to their profile. **I already know the rows are different** because I'm using the `SequenceEqual` to determine that.

At the moment I've written and debugged the following code:

```
if (currentRow.ItemArray.SequenceEqual(updatedRow)) { return; }
var updates = currentRow.ItemArray
    .Where((o, i) =>
    {
        if (o == null && updatedRow[i] == null) { return false; }
        else if (o == null && updatedRow[i] != null) { return true; }
        else if (o.Equals(updatedRow[i])) { return false; }
        return true;
    })
    .Select((o, i) =>
    {
        return new AppServices.NotificationData
        {
            Key = updatedRow.Table.Columns[i].ColumnName,
            Value = Convert.ToString(updatedRow[i])
        };
    }).ToList();
```

**But there are two problems with this code:**

1. It seems really inefficient to me because it's going through each value in the `ItemArray` and then building a key value pair **if the values differ.**
2. **It doesn't actually work** because the `i` sent into the `Select` isn't correct (e.g. if the second column changed, `1`, the index sent into the `Select` is actually `0`. Honestly, that makes sense, but I'm not sure exactly how to get what I want here.

**CONSTRAINT:** I'd like to use LINQ here.

**NOTE:** I'm only comparing two rows (i.e. it's not going to be going through a list of rows).

*What is the appropriate LINQ statement for what I'm trying to do here?*

**UPDATE:** It really feels like I just need to use:

```
currentRow.ItemArray.Intersect(updatedRow.ItemArray)
```

but the problem with that is I don't have any idea what field that is so I can't build a key value pair. In other words, I get back only the differences, but I've no clue what the index is so I can't go get a column name based off of those values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var updates = currentRow.ItemArray
    .Select((o, i) => new { Row = o, Index = i })
    .Where(r => (r.Row == null && updatedRow[r.Index] != null)
        || (r.Row != null && updatedRow[r.Index] != null
        && !r.Row.Equals(updatedRow[r.Index])))
    .Select(r => new
    {
        Key = updatedRow.Table.Columns[r.Index].ColumnName,
        Value = Convert.ToString(updatedRow[r.Index])
    }).ToList();
```

Comment: This works my friend, I just needed to fix the syntax because it was off a bit with parenthesis and such.

Answer (score 3):

Honestly you're not going to lose much code clarity by using a `for` loop.

```
public IEnumerable<AppServices.NotificationData> GetUpdates(DataRow currentRow, DataRow updatedRow)
{
    if (currentRow.ItemArray.SequenceEqual(updatedRow)) yield break;

    var length = currentRow.ItemArray.Length;
    for(var i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        var currentCol = currentRow[i];
        var updatedCol = updatedRow[i];

        if (currentCol == null && updatedCol == null) continue;
        else if (currentCol == null && updatedCol != null) continue;
        else if (currentCol.Equals(updatedCol)) continue;

        yield return new AppServices.NotificationData
                     {
                        Key = updatedRow.Table.Columns[i].ColumnName,
                        Value = Convert.ToString(updatedCol)
                     };
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 as I don't really disagree with you, the constraint is coming from outside and thus I wanted to comply with it if possible. If it wasn't possible I was going to push back, with this approach in fact.

Answer (score 1):

In general, I consider using array index values in LINQ to be a "code smell", and this is a good example of why: the Where clause, in generating a new sequence of values, destroys the illusion that the Select clause is working on the same collection as before.

A quick hack to get around this right now (though I don't think it is quite yet the right solution), would be to swap your Where and Select clauses, essentially:

```
if (currentRow.ItemArray.SequenceEqual(updatedRow)) { return; }
var updates = currentRow.ItemArray
    .Select((o, i) =>
    {
        if (o == null && updatedRow[i] == null || o.Equals(updatedRow[i])) { return null; }
        else return new AppServices.NotificationData
        {
            Key = updatedRow.Table.Columns[i].ColumnName,
            Value = Convert.ToString(updatedRow[i])
        };
    }).Where(o => o != null).ToList();
```